How to set provider name in consent screen in Microsoft 365 OAuth2 for Authentication
I have an existing application where I want to change the service provider name. I am trying to do this from Microsoft Entra Admin Center.
I looked through all the options but cannot find how the application provider name can be updated. Please see OAuth2Test in the diagram.

